# Objective-C: How to stop a NSTimer?

Tags: xcode

how would i go about stopping my timer whenever I try to do [myTimer invalidate]; I get an error.

My Timer:

```
    NSTimer *MyTimer;
MyTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0
                                         target: self
                                       selector: @selector(handleTimer)
                                       userInfo: nil
                                        repeats: YES];
```

Here's the if statement I have set up for the timer.

```
-(void)handleTimer{

if (count >= 0) {
    [secondsLeft setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)count]]; //displays current value of count to UI
    count--; //Incrementally decreases count
} else if(count <= 0) { //if the timer runs out then...
self.secondsLeft.text = @"Times's Up!";
    [answerButtonOutlet setEnabled:NO];
    self.secondsLeftToAnswer.text = @"Answer is 30";
} else if([self.secondsLeftToAnswer.text isEqual: @"Correct!"]) { //else if statement if user gets answer Correct.
    [myTimer invalidate]; // error occurs here. "Unknown receiver 'myTimer': did you mean NSTimer?
}

    }
```

How would I make it so that I don't get the error in the second else if statement? I'm brand new to coding so I'm sure its probably pretty obvious but I can't figure it out for the life of me. Thanks!

Comment: In your first chunk of code you write the variable as `MyTimer` and in the second you have it as `myTimer` (lower case).  The compiler is case sensitive so these are not the same variable.  Beyond that, it's not clear what the scope of `MyTimer` in the first snippet is.  Is `MyTimer` declared in a function, or as a property on a class, or what?  If `MyTimer` is just declared in some other function, it will not be defined in `handleTimer`.

Comment: By convention method and variable names begin with a lowercase letter. Following conventions can make your code easier to read and reduce bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Since `NSTimer *MyTimer;`

`[myTimer invalidate];` should be `[MyTimer invalidate];`

Answer (score 1):

You're better off just using the `timer` argument that gets passed to the handler method.  In other words, you need an extra colon in the selector to indicate that the handler takes an argument

```
selector: @selector(handleTimer:)   // note the colon at the end
```

Then your handler looks like this

```
-(void)handleTimer:(NSTimer *)theTimer 
{
    ...

    else if([self.secondsLeftToAnswer.text isEqual: @"Correct!"]) { 
        [theTimer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `[myTimer invalidate]`, when you should really have:

```
[MyTimer invalidate];
MyTimer = nil;
```

Try this change and let me know what happens. Also, throw an NSLog in that `else if` to make sure it's firing.